# webClient.DownloadString load new string

Tags: windows-phone, webclient

it's my code:

```
public void pobierzSuchary()
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://../michal/suchary.txt"));
        }

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
            ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
                Message = "Suchary zostały pobrane"
            };

            String[] sucharyTab = e.Result.Split('@');
            MessageBox.Show(sucharyTab[1]);
..
}
```

Button runs pobierzSuchary() and is downloading string, I have a problem when I press second time button. Then i see in messagebox older value, but i changed string on server(manually). I have to disable the applications and run again to see new string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the windows phone automatically caches values for repeat calls.

Just append a random number onto the end of your webclient call

Something like this

```
   Random ran = new Random();
   webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://../michal/suchary.txt?ran="+ran.next().toString()));
```